# How to create graph with large number of points in R?

Tags: r, graph

I have a large dataset contains a large number of nodes; more than 25000 nodes, organized in a `.csv` file. The structure is similar to the following :

```
node freq
a     3
b     2
c     5
```

I want to create a graph from these node in which edges between nodes are constructed by a function of the `freq` column. I have used the `rgraph` function from `sna` package, such as:

```
num_nodes <- length(data$node)
  pLink = data$freq/10
  # create 1 graph with  nodes and link proability, graph loops = FALSE
  graph_adj= rgraph(num_nodes,1,pLink,"graph",FALSE)
  graph <- graph.adjacency(graph_adj, mode="undirected")
```

The above code is running in case of small number of nodes, but with large number of nodes, The R session aborted with the following Error:

```
Error: C stack usage 19924416 is too close to the limit
```

Is there another way to create a graph with the mentioned properties: a large number of nodes and edges are created with probability?

Comment: Have you tried [`igraph`](http://igraph.org/r/) package? It is normally used for plotting networks

Comment: I tried it, but didn't find a way to let the edges be created based on the `freq` function

Comment: The error message you're getting is often a sign of infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks @TomasKalibera ,  the problem was in probability calculation as sometimes it exceeds 1 !